# Submanifold of complex projective space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to solve the following problem for my introductory course in Differential Analysis and Geometry.

$M = \{[z]\in \mathbb{C}P^n:\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}z_i^m=0\}$ is an embedded submanifold of the complex projective space. I want to try the regular value theorem but I do not know how I can show that $0$ is a regular value. Where we have $m$ an integer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\sum z_i^m$ is not even a well-defined function on $\mathbb{C}P^n$, so you definitely need a different approach (or at least, a more careful way of using the regular value theorem).

Comment: Why is it not well-defined? I did forget to specifiy that m is an integer.

Comment: @Charles:  If, say, $m =2$ and $n=1$, then $f([1:1]) = 2$ while $f([i:i]) = -2$, so $f([1:1])\neq f([i:i])$ even though $[1:1] = [i:i]$.  Thus, $f$ is not, in general, a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Either work in the ($n+1$) standard coordinate charts on $\Bbb CP^n$ or ... for future reference ... prove the following lemma:

If $f$ is a homogeneous polynomial on $\Bbb C^{n+1}$, then $0$ is a regular value of $f$ on $\Bbb C^{n+1}-\{0\}$ if and only if $0$ is a regular value of $F(z_1,\dots,z_n) = f(1,z_1/z_0,\dots,z_n/z_0)$.